# Update Crud Operation in PHP with form validation and action

Tags: php, mysql

[index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDD7H.jpg)

[edit_product_form.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRCqZ.jpg)

Data is not being pulled from database when update button is clicked.
how do you write SQL statement that will pull current data table when update button is clicked.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    index.php

```
// edit button
<td><form action="edit_product_form.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id"
                           value="<?php echo $product['productID']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="category_id"
                           value="<?php echo $product['categoryID']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </form></td>


edit_product_form.php

<?php
require('database.php');
$query = 'SELECT *
          FROM categories
          ORDER BY categoryID';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$categories = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- the head section -->
<head>
    <title>My Guitar Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<!-- the body section -->
<body>
    <header><h1>Update Form</h1></header>

    <main>
        <h1>Update</h1>
        <form action="add_product.php" method="post"
              id="add_product_form">


            <label>Code:</label>
            <input type="text" name="code"><br>

            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>

            <label>List Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="price"><br>

            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Update"><br>
        </form>
        <p><a href="index.php">View Product List</a></p>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> My Guitar Shop, Inc.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

// form for edit button actiom

```
edit_product.php

<?php

// Validate inputs
if ($product_id == NULL || $product_id == FALSE || $category_id == NULL || 
        $category_id == FALSE || empty($code) || empty($name) || 
        $price == NULL || $price == FALSE ) {
    $error = "Invalid product data. Check all fields and try again.";
    include('error.php');
} else {
    // If valid, update the product in the database
    require_once('database.php');
    $query = 'UPDATE products
              SET categoryID = :category_id,
                  productCode = :code,
                  productName = :name,
                  listPrice = :price
               WHERE productID = :product_id';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id);
    $statement->bindValue(':code', $code);
    $statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $statement->bindValue(':price', $price);
    $statement->bindValue(':product_id', $product_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();

    // Display the Product List page
    include('index.php');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are printing categories anywhere, if that's what you're asking for. Please clarify your needs and what you do expect your code to do. However, i strongly suggest you to invest some time learning OOP principles, pick one framework you like (laravel, simfony, cake, etc.) and drop that page-based coding.

Comment: I am trying to print table in edit_product_page.php and the update. I have this project for class i have working add and delete but update button is not pulling data. I am trying to add data to with echo.